# Sending process to different nodes with mpi4py

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-computing, mpi4py

I have a function that I would like to be evaluated across multiple nodes in a cluster. I've gotten simple examples to run on our cluster using `MPI4py`, but was hoping to find a python package that makes things a little more user friendly (like implementing the `map` feature of `multiprocessing`) but also has a little more control over how many processes get spawned and on which of the nodes. I've seen a few packages that implement `map` but not any that control how many processes are spawned on each node.

The following code gets close to illustrating what I mean. However, instead of writing it in the typical way you would with `MPI4py` I've written it like you would with the `map` function. I wrote it this way because this is ultimately how I'd like to implement the code (with a module that emulates `map`) and because I'm not quite sure how'd I'd write it using MPI to achieve what I want to do.

```
from numpy import *
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(n):
  random.seed(n)
  a = random.randn(1000,1000)
  b = random.randn(1000,1000)
  c = dot(a, b)
  return c.mean()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = Pool(processes=4)
  results = pool.map(foo, range(4))
  print results
```

The reason why I want to control the number of processes sent to each node is that some of the instructions inside of `foo` can be multithreaded (like `dot` which would also be linked to the MKL libraries).

If I have a cluster of 12 computers with 2 cores each, I'd like to just send out one job to each of the 12 nodes, where it would implicitly take advantage of both cores. I don't want to spawn 24 jobs (one for each core) because I'm worried about possible thread-thrashing when both processes try to use both cores. I also can't just spawn 12 processes because I can't be certain it will send one to each node and not 2 to the first 6 nodes.

First off, should this be a major concern? How much of an effect would running 24 processes instead of 12 have on performance?

If it will make a difference, is there a python package that will overlay on top of `MPI4py` and do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same thing, so I wrote up a [proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/donkirkby/be2d583d0eb53daf82f7) that keeps track of how many worker processes are idle on each host. If you have a job that will use two threads, then it waits until a host has two idle workers, assigns the job to one of those workers, and keeps the other worker idle until the job is finished.

To specify how many processes to launch on each host, you use [a hostfile](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-hostfile).

The key is for the root process to receive messages from any other process:

```
source_host, worker_rank, result = MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
```

That way, it finds out as soon as each job is finished. Then when it's ready, it sends the job to a specific worker:

```
comm.send(row, dest=worker_rank)
```

At the end, it tells all the workers to shut down by sending a `None` message:

```
comm.send(None, dest=worker_rank)
```

After I wrote this, I found [jbornschein's mpi4py task pull example](https://github.com/jbornschein/mpi4py-examples/blob/master/09-task-pull.py). It doesn't handle the thread counts for each job, but I like the way it uses tags for different message types.